# 500 Internal Server Error... browser-specific?

Tags: php, apache

It is my understanding that a response code of 500 means that the server encountered an error, possibly a misconfiguration or a timeout.

On my current project I've been getting a lot of intermittent 500-responses (about one in every 100 pageloads). But only in Internet Explorer.

What could possibly cause this? The error is apparently completely random. The best we can get from the logs is:

> [Tue Jul 24 18:57:09 2012] [error] [client 66.83.159.2] Handler for (null) returned invalid result code 70007

I'm using Apache2.2 and PHP5.4.5.

Comment: [Nobody knew in 2011 either.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657692/what-does-invalid-result-code-70007-mean-how-do-i-fix-it) Would you happen to be uploading files?

Comment: [Ah, here we are.](http://serverfault.com/questions/231331/handler-for-null-returned-invalid-result-code-70007-causing-error-500) And it's probably not a PHP problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 errors are not necessarily browser specific, but this may be caused by data that is passed to your server from the client.

There should be a php error log in addition to your Apache error log. Check that log or change your settings (on the problematic page) to display errors until you find what you're looking for.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE`, and `display_errors` is on with appropriate prepend and append strings to make the whole thing user-friendly. The request is NOT getting received by PHP, as not even the first command runs.

Comment: Perhaps this applies to you: http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=25822&page=1#6  Other than that I'm stumped.

Comment: That seems promising, but to my knowledge I don't have any proxies between me and the internet. Any idea how I would find out if this is the case or not?

Comment: @Kolink sorry, no. But hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Accepted as "best answer" - we changed the timeout that Apache waits for PHP from five minutes down to five seconds, and for some reason the errors stopped happening.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old thread but maybe it helps someone who (like me) finds this on google as one of the first results:
If you get a 500-error in one browser and not in the other it may actually not be a server error, but a malfunctioning cookie.

I had the issue where I got a 500 when trying to log in with firefox, but when testing in chrome it worked flawlessly. After clearing the cookies for this page in ff it worked again there too.

Answer (score 1):

Generally something is crashing in the server-side, in this case PHP, so you may want to put in exception blocks and log what would normally go up.

The user should see some useful message, such as *Error, please try again*, but ultimately this should help you narrow down the problem.

Now, it may be that you will want to return a 500 error, if this is a REST service, but if just returning something a user can see then you should make it more user-friendly.

If you can duplicate it somehow, then use Fiddler2 (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), to to get all the back and forth communication between your browser and the server and see if IE is sending something different than other browsers.

Comment: How does making the (non-existant due to PHP never actually being reached) error message user-friendly help solve the issue?

Comment: @Kolink - It doesn't solve the issue, but, from a user POV it is annoying to get an error message, give the user some useful information, and, if you can return something useful, then you are catching the problem and it should be logged.  If you get something still that you expect to be logged, then it will help you know if you are logging the problems.

Comment: The project is still in development. I am the only user.

Comment: @Kolink - Again, even if you are the only user, if you don't get the error message, but you get a message that means you caught an exception and logged it, then you can check, but even when you go live, catch exceptions and give the user something useful.